# Why doesn't my "wait" function work in Capybara? I get a "not string or proc" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

When I add a wait function to an `expect(page).to_have_content` statement, I get the following error:
**WARNING: ignoring the provided expectation message argument ({:wait=>20}) since it is not a string or a proc.**
For reference, here is how my wait statement looks:

```
When 'I change the language' do
  expect(page).to have_content 'Primary Text', wait: 10
  first('div[data-testid="SelectLanguage"]').click
  first('li[data-testid="SelectLanguage__Select__es"]').click
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Rubys optional ()s in method calls is that it allows for unclear/ambiguous statements when passing the output of methods as parameters to other methods. In your

```
expect(page).to have_content 'Primary Text', wait: 10
```

the `wait: 10` is actually being passed as the second argument to ‘to’ rather than `have_content` so it's being interpreted as

```
expect(page).to(have_content('Primary Text'), wait: 10)
```

To get your desired behavior you need to do

```
expect(page).to have_content('Primary Text', wait: 10)
```

One benefit of using something like `rubocop` is that it will flag situations like this for you